# Sharing post from my WP blog to facebook, only appears the url of site, not the post, why?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I can't share my post to my fb from my [page](http://www.piladeleche.com), it only shares the page url instead..

I tried the debugger tool and it came with this:

> Object at URL 'http://www.piladeleche.com/' of type 'website' is
>   invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was
>   not provided. Warning Errors That Must Be Fixed Object Missing a
>   Required Value    Object at URL 'http://www.piladeleche.com/' of type
>   'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type
>   'string' was not provided.

Any idea how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: This is what you send to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.piladeleche.com%2F

Comment: sorry but im lost >.<

Comment: Your server is strange. When Facebook request a post url it get this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.piladeleche.com%2Flos-15-tatuajes-mas-impresionantes-de-one-piece-adivina-la-12%2F

Comment: i know, could u gimme an advise to fix this? :s

Comment: Remove the meta refresh when someone loads the page

Comment: how do i remove that?

Comment: also ensure you have all the valid og tags you are missing such as og:title defined on your site.